# How to use spring security rest grails plugin to authenticate form-based login

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

Preface: ***I created the following issue in GitHub of the plugin and Alvaro Sanchez, the author of the plugin, recommended me to ask here which is the dedicated discussion channel for it***.

We are migrating our Grails-based application to Kubernetes to allow multiple instances running simultaneously. The inherent problem is that the application will ask users to re-login if the request is served by the other pod that is not the previously same pod. We want to replace session-based authentication with token-based authentication.

I have come across [writing on medium](https://medium.com/@lucasaquiles/grails-3-3-with-spring-security-core-and-spring-security-rest-plugin-6bcbc98c8fb) explaining how to use this plugin come long the source code published on [GitHub](https://github.com/lucasaquiles/auth-blank-template), however, this tutorial didn't show how to customise the form-based login or something along those lines.

The key point here is to verify the existence of the defined token in order to redirect the login URL. However, I don't actually understand how and where we could intervene `LoginController` spring security core to check both `username` and `token`.

Apart from that, I cannot find any tutorials as well as documentation relevant to our need, so then I have raised this problem which someone experienced users can share their solutions.

If you have any idea, helpful tutorials or source code, could you please share with us?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Switching to JWT tokens is not the solution to the problem you're facing. Using something that stores the session externally such as 'spring-session' or similar would be.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @erichelgeson. I would love to show you my implementation.

Comment: Please check spring sessions docs, they are quite good and have grails examples.